# Android Mediaplayer Selecttrack method fails

Tags: java, android

I am using the mediaplayer feature on Android. I basically have songs in the raw folder and I would just like to change to a new track but it fails. One music file plays and then I press a button after or during the music playing to skip to a random track but it fails.

Current code

```
mediaplayer.stop();
try {
        mediaplayer.prepareAysn();
        mediaPlayer.selectTrack(randomtrack_num - 1);

    }
    catch(Exception e){}
mediaplayer.start();
```

The error that I receive:

- MediaPlayer: start called in state 64
- MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
- MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)

I tried this without mediaplayer.stop() and still included mediaplayer.start() at the end and it would just replay the same track again.

Am I missing something? 
Please let me know.

**2nd Approach**
After reading the document I realized this can only be done in the prepared state which I assume in my second approach it should work but it is not.

```
  mediaPlayer.stop();

    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

          try{
               mp.selectTrack(randomtrack_num - 1);

              }catch(Exception e){}

            mp.start();

        }
    });
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

I get this error:/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
Basically the same track plays again and it does not go to the selected track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `mediaplayer.start()` in wrong state. Firstly read this documentation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

You will have a better idea of correct implementation.

EDITED:

```
   String[] url ; // initiliaze your URL array here
   MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
   myMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
   try { 
       myMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url[0]);
       myMediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
   } catch (IOException e) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "mp3 not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       e.printStackTrace();
   } 

   //mp3 will be started after completion of preparing... 
   myMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

       @Override 
       public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
           player.start();
       } 

   });
```

Playing different track after completions

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() { 
 @Override 
 public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
 { 

    myMediaPlayer.reset(); 
   /* load the new source */ 
   myMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url[position]);//select the path according to your need 
   /* Prepare the mediaplayer */ 
   myMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

}

Comment: I added mediaplayer.prepareAysnc(); inside the try and catch field. It still does not go to another track. I do however get this error, "E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set"

Comment: I made a second attempt using the setOnPreparedListener() and I am still unable to fix this issue.

Comment: Where is the .selecttrack() method in your answer above?

Comment: May I know what are trying to achieve, I will be help you better that way.

Comment: If you have a data source which contains multiple tracks and you want to switch to next track or lets suppose you want to shuffle. do it in onCompletionListener.

Comment: OK so you can re-use the setDataSource method again. I will try that. But inside the setOnCompletelistener mp is variable that should be used not myMediaPlayer correct?

Comment: The onCompletionListener method is that called everytime I call .start() method? What I am trying to do is select a random track. Which is why i was using the .selecttrack() method but it failed. I will use the .setDataSource again to see if it works.

Comment: onCompletionListener is called only when your track completes.

Comment: OK then that is not what I want then to automatically play a new song. I have a button press to play a random track song whenever you desire. Is there another method I can use then? Can I just add the .setDataSource in the onPrepared method?

Comment: You can use the code inside onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) method on click of your button to achieve this.